# How to resolve mysql error number 1064 when connecting with node js application?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Guys I am using nodejs and trying to connect to MySQL server in my pc.

here is my code

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "*******",
  database: "node-testing",
});

connection.connect();

connection.query("SELECT * FROM test-1", (err, rows, fields) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(fields);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

connection.end();
```

when I execute the following file, I got this error

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM test-1'
```

can someone please help me solve this issue. Thank you

Comment: DO NOT use spaces or dashes in db/table or column names, correct your column name as `test_1` or `test1`

Comment: At least try to put test-1 into single quotes... `'test-1'` if that's even valid table name...  `-` is SQL Minus operator

Comment: `'test-1'` would be invalid. `"test-1"` is the correct ANSI syntax. `\`test-1\`` too

Comment: @ikiK not quotes but backticks like `

Comment: Note that to add backticks in markdown inlined code, you can use backslash `This \`is cool\`, like this : \\``